# How to call a __private static method from other methods in python

Tags: python, class, methods, static

I'm assuming a private static method in a Python class is something that can and should be done. But perhaps in actuality, I should simply be using a module private method outside the class.

I want to understand calling different kinds of static methods from various locations:

I have a Python class with a private and a public static method. I want to call them from other places, and from each other.

When outside the class and calling the public static method, I must add the classname. i.e.

```py
m = MyClass.the_staticmethod(100) # I must use the classname as a prefix
```

See questions in code:

```py
    class Myclass():
        @staticmethod
        __my_privatestaticmethod(myparam):
             return myparam

        @staticmethod
        def the_staticmethod(myparam):
            # will the following work?
            result = __my_staticmethod(1) # will this work?

            # data-mingling set as private, so following line cannot work!
            result = Myclass.__my_staticmethod(2) # this cannot work. 

            result = the_staticmethod(3) # will this work without the prefix

            return result
 

        def __my_privatemethod(self, param1):
            # which of the following are valid?
            return __my_staticmethod(11) # will this work?

            # data-mingling set as private, so following line cannot work!
            return Myclass.__my_staticmethod(12) # this cannot work. 

            return the_staticmethod(13) # will this work without the prefix of the class? 
            
            return self.the_staticmethod(14) # will this work. Is the self also considered the class? 

            return  Myclass.the_staticmethod(15) # this of course works. 
            

        def the_method(param1):
            return __my_staticmethod(param1) # will this work?
```

If the answers to 1 and 11 are no, then the conclusion is that you cannot make a private static method.

I would then make a private module method outside the class without a decorator. This would be equivalent to the private static class method.

```py
    def __my_privatemodulemethod(param1):
         return param1
```

and can call it from anywhere in my module, without a prefix.

Comment: Python doesn't have private vs. public class elements.  If it exists, you can reference it.

Comment: Python is not `C#`. I  suppose what you're trying to achieve has a much more `pythonic` equivalent.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. You can find out which of these calls work by trying to run them one by one; what do you need us for?

Comment: A `staticmethod` is a method that doesn't receive a `cls` or `self` argument. If you do want to access other methods of the same class/instance, then that method really shouldn't be `static`.

Comment: yes, that's why I explicitly used the word __private, and used dunder in the example for data mingling.

Comment: I'm asking because there is nowhere to find a summary of @staticmethod running from private/public (and there IS a notion of private/public achieved with data mingling).  Also because I don't know if there are differences in different versions of python. And also because as opposed to other languages there is no easy to use simple python fiddle. And also because the python documentation is always clunky.

Comment: @pashute this last sentence about Python's doc quality is not going to get you much help...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As deceze already mentionned in a comment, in Python a `staticmethod` is a method that doesn't take the instance *nor* the class as first argument. Since Python has no implicit `this` pointer, obviously a `staticmethod` has no way to reference the current class, so it cannot call another `staticmethod` on the current class. The obvious solution here is to use `classmethods` instead (classmethods takes the current class as first argument):

```
class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    def _protected(cls, arg):
        print("{}._protected() called with {}".format(cls.__name__, arg))

    @classmethod
    def public(cls, arg):
        cls._protected(arg)
```

> there IS a notion of private/public achieved with data mingling

s/data mingling/name mangling/g ;)

"dunder" names and the name mangling mechanism don't make anything private:

```
class Foo(object):
    @staticmethod
    def __not_private():
        print("peek a boo")


Foo._Foo_not_private()
```

[As the "clunky" doc states](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references), the point here is mostly to avoid *accidental* overridding of some important implementation part of a base class. Practically this is very seldom used, and most of the time not even really needed. The convention to indicate "implementation" methods and attribute is to name them with a *single* leading underscore.

As a side note, snarky remarks about Python's doc quality is not going to get you much helping friends.

Comment: Thanks, Bruno. So Python programmers are mostly Python lovers and they dislike any remarks about the documentation and the way it is presented?  

Sorry!!  I did not mean to offend. I seriously thought that anybody from the newer c like languages (pascal, dotnet and especially c#, java etc.) looking through this documentation (a bit old-fashioned, lacking inner links and examples for each parameter and its usage)  would find it hard to understand how to write code.

Comment: @pashute I learned Python with the official doc and never found it "clunky". But if you think you can improve it, please contribute - this is a free open source project.

Comment: is there a place to post a suggestion about this?  And have hundreds of programmers add their examples and links to each and every option and function?

Comment: OK thanks. subscribed and will try to get things moving.

Answer (score 2):

I tried every possible thing which can be done in calling static methods and the results were surprising.
For understanding this thing, there are few things, we need to recall:

1. (i) Private members can be accessed WITHIN THE CLASS, i.e. in other methods.
   (ii) To access private members outside the class we have to use _ClassName__privateMember.
2. Static methods can only be accessed using class or object.

Extra point which can help:

3. Any method of a class can be accessed using class. For instance method you have to pass object as self argument i.e., Myclass.instanceMethod(obj,params).

   ```
   class Myclass():
       @staticmethod
       def __myPrivateStaticMethod(myparam):
           return myparam   
       @staticmethod
       def myStaticMethod(myparam):   
           # result = __myPrivateStaticMethod(1)           # This will not work. Point 2   
           # data-mingling set as private outside the class, but can be accessed within the class
           result = Myclass.__myPrivateStaticMethod(2)     # This will work. Point 1 (i)   
           # result = myStaticMethod(3)                    # This will not work. Point 2   
           return result   
       def __myPrivateMethod(self, param1):   
           # result = __myPrivateStaticMethod(11)          # This will not work. Point 2   
           # data-mingling set as private outside the class, but can be accessed within the class
           result = Myclass.__myPrivateStaticMethod(12)    # This will work. Point 1 (i)   
           # result = myStaticMethod(13)                   # This will not work Point 2   
           # self is object of the class
           result = self.myStaticMethod(14)                # This will work Point 2   
           # this of course works. Point 2
           result = Myclass.myStaticMethod(15)
           return result   
       def instanceMethod(self, param1):
           # return __myPrivateStaticMethod(param1)        # This will not work. Point 2
           Myclass._Myclass__myPrivateMethod(self, 45)     # This will work. Point 3
           pass   
   obj = Myclass()
   obj._Myclass__myPrivateStaticMethod(45)                 # Point 1 (ii) and Point 2
   obj.myStaticMethod(45)                                  # Point 2
   obj._Myclass__myPrivateMethod(45)                       # Point 1 (ii)
   obj.instanceMethod(45)                                  
   Myclass._Myclass__myPrivateMethod(obj,45)               # Point 3
   ```

Hope Everything will be clear.